# Populate a userform text box with a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple userform that I would like to populate a text box with the value of a cell. Seems pretty simple but it is not populating and I can't figure out why, can someone take a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to populate `TextBoxCurrentCCBuffer` with `Sheets("Closing Costs").Range("D32")`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBoxCurrentCCBuffer.Value = Sheets("Closing Costs").Range("D32").Value
    If TextBoxCCBuffer.Value = "" Then
        Unload Me
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Worksheets("Closing Costs").Range("D32").Value = TextBoxCCBuffer.Value
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, it looks like when you click the button, you're setting the value of the textbox, then immediately writing that same value back to the cell and closing the userform. Are you maybe trying to populate the textbox when the form is loaded instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of what you are doing, you can populate the textbox in the userform initialize event.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
TextBoxCurrentCCBuffer.Value = Sheets("Closing Costs").Range("D32").Value
End Sub
```